# XSD: Unable to use type defined in the same XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writting the following XSD, however I'm having problems with it. For whatever reason, I'm not being allowed to  use my simple types that I define in my XSD. I'm getting this error: `Cannot resolve the name 'mySimpleType1' to a(n) 'simpleType definition' component.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://myNamespace" 
    targetNamespace="http://myDifferentNamespace" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:simpleType name="mySimpleType1">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Added"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Modified"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Deleted"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="mySimpleType2">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="foo"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="bar"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:attributeGroup name="myAttributeGroup">
        <xsd:attribute name="attribute1" type="mySimpleType1" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="attribute2" type="mySimpleType2" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No namespace prefix is on your target namespace...

I would suggest reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258639(v=sql.80).aspx

Here's another good guide to creating schema: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/xml-schema/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `mySimpleType1` is lookuped from xmlns `http://myNamespace` (no prefix in type - xmlns without suffix is used), but you have defined it in `http://myDifferentNamespace` (defined by targetNamespace).

**You probably want to use `xmlns` identical with `targetNamespace`.**

Otherwise you need to define for example `xmlns:mydiff="http://myDifferentNamespace"` and to refer types as `type="mydiff:mySimpleType1"`.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336017/1576461 for more info about xmlns.