# XML won't validate against certain XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, prefix, xml-validation, xml-error

The XML (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mx:XMLimport xmlns:mx="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Leverancier>nn</Leverancier>
    <Bestandsversie>1.1.0.0</Bestandsversie>
</mx:XMLimport>
```

The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="XMLimport">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Leverancier" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
              <xsd:element name="Bestandsversie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

If I remove the `mx:` prefix from the root element of the XML it validates just fine. I'm lost in name spaces and I'm searching the internet for several hours now. I can't change the XML so the XSD have to be adapted to allow the `mx:` prefix. The validator gives this error:

```
ERROR: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}XMLimport':
       No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

Comment: There's something very wrong with that XML. It's is using `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` as its namespace, which is obviously the namespace of the XSD format (which, as far as I can tell, has no `XMLimport` element). Where did you get this XML?

Comment: Hi JL, The XML is from a vendor, the vendor can't/won't change it. If I just remove the "mx:" prefix from the XML it works fine. Since that's not possible in production modus I have to change my own XSD.

Comment: You're not the only one who is lost with regard to XML namespaces -- the source of that XML is obviously also lost.  There is no XMLImport element in the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.  If the vendor really can't or won't change it, I'd suggest getting a new vendor.  If you can't or won't do that, fix the XML anyway:  run it through a filter to clean up the namespace declarations before validating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is what should the XSD look like to match your XML. This is the corrected XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="XMLimport">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Leverancier" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="Bestandsversie" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>  
</xsd:schema>
```

Your XSD doesn't define a `targetNamespace` attribute. Hence, your **XMLimport** must show without a namespace in instance documents; this is why when you remove the namespace from your **XMLimport** in the XML document, it becomes valid.

If you add `targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` you'll now have an XSD that will validate your XML; in general, the value of the targetNamespace must match the namespace of your document element (chameleon XSDs are a special case).

Another thing at play here is `elementFormDefault` which by default is `unqualified`. This setting is that which makes the inner elements `Leverancier` and `Bestandsversie` without a namespace.

Another thing to notice is that while it is highly unusual to see user defined content targeting the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace, there's no provision in the XSD 1.0 spec which would explicitly prohibit users to target this namespace. This is unlike the other namespace you see in your sample XML, `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`: it is explicitly prohibited to target this namespace in user defined XSDs.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190572/targetnamespace-and-xmlns-without-prefix-what-is-the-difference/7200002#7200002) might help, too.

Comment: The `Leverancier` and `Bestandsversie` elements of the source XML appear to be in the null namespace. Wouldn't that mean they need to be defined in a separate XSD?

Comment: @JLRishe, no; this is why I pointed out `elementFormDefault` in my response.